# Rewrite the Base URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

My Domain example.com points to the directory public_html. In the directory public_html/php is my index.php file.

Now I want that the URL *example.com* points to *public_html/php/index.php*. I must do this with mod_rewrite because I have no access to the httpd.conf to do something wth Alias oder DocumentBase.

In the directory public_html is my .htacces filewith the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} exaple.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /php/index.php [L,QSA]
```

This do half of the job, because when I enter something like *example.com/s* in my browser it points to *public_html/php/index.php* as I want it to do. But when I just enter *example.com* it points to *public_html*.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

The `!-f` flag means "if the requested file doesn't exist". When accessing example.com, the Apache `DirectoryIndex` directive redirects the request to `/public_html/index.php`, does this file exist? Because if it does, your `RewriteRule` is ignored. You have to either remove the `RewriteCond` above, or remove the `/public_html/index.php` file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your hint, there was a index.html in the *public_html* folder from my hoster. I deleted this file and everything works. Thank you very much :)